# How to insert into parent and child tables at once in bookshelf.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

I got a table called `companies` and another called `companies_posts`, where `company_posts.company_id` is a foreign key to `companies.id`

Supposing I got the following `json`:

```
  {

       "name" : "Teste",
       "username" : "teste1",
       "password" : "teste1",
       "email" : "teste2@teste",
       "photo" : "teste",
       "description" : "teste",
       "company_posts" : [
          {"text" : "oi"},
          {"text" : "olá"}
       ]

   }
```

Is there any way in [`bookshelf.js`](http://bookshelfjs.org/) to insert it at once? Like mongodb, I suppose. Or I need to `insert company`, get `lastInsertId` and then `insert` each `company_posts` right after?

Thanks.

Edit: (Btw, I just learned how to `select` using `withRelated` and `hasMany`. Now I must learn how to `insert` / `update`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, bookshelf.js uses knex.js, which is based on relational database. Thus, you must firstly insert the company. In the callback function you get the inserted id, and you can insert the posts as well.

You can of course use transactions for this, which have been greatly improved in the recent update of knex.js.

I haven't tested this, but I think something like that should work, more or less:

```
var Company = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'companies',
  posts: function(){
    return this.hasMany(Post);
  }
});

var Post = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'posts',
  companies: function(){
    return this.belongsTo(Company);
  }
});

new Company().save({...}).then(function(company){
    new Post().save({
        ...
        company_id: company.get('id')
    }).then(function(post){
        //final result
    });
});
```